# KVM switch not working

Tags: laptop

I have a KVM switch that has previously worked well with both a Dell and an HP Docking station.  I recently tried to hook it to a docking station for an HP Pavilion DV6-1355dx Notebook T6600/x64/x64.  1st issue was I needed an adapter, (I was told the adapter was needed to convert the docking station because it is an analog output and the KVM switch was digital).  I installed an adapter and the computer/docking station still is not acknowledging the KVM Switch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. What model KVM switch?

Answer (score 0):

I work with KVM switches from time to time and they seem very touchy and break pretty easy. Something that I noticed is when you are messing with the cable configuration, and suddenly nothing works, a power cycle usually fixes the issue. A lot of KVM switches don't have a dedicated power cable, if this is the case, then unplug all the cables from it and then start fresh. I hope this  helps!